# After installing nodejs , npm is fetching typos.json error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

C:\Users\praja>npm --version
Error: Cannot find module './typos.json'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\lib\read-json.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetcher.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\update-notifier.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:9:13)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall Node.js – you're somehow missing a module.

Comment: can you explain in briefly i have tried multiple times installing and uninstalling and again re-installing nodejs!

Comment: Uninstall Node.js, remove (or move or rename) `C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm` if it still exists, reinstall Node.js. If that still fails, there's something other wrong with your computer.

Comment: (Also, which version of Node.js are you installing? Where did you get the installer from?)

Comment: Official nodejs website .Win LTS 16.17.0 msi

Comment: Yes as you said i finally removed Uninstall Node.js, remove (or move or rename) C:\Users\praja\AppData\Roaming\npm if it still exists, reinstall Node.js. now its done.